# Which elasitcsearch node should i query from my application

Tags: elasticsearch

If I were to set up my cluster on elastic with 3 master node and 5 to 10 data nodes which node IP address should I actually use in my application to query elastic. I am following Hot warm architecture for elastic but from what I have understood is the master node should always be responsible for handling an incoming request and then coordinating that request to further node in the cluster and to operate on the final response.

So should I only use master node IP addresses in my application to talk with the cluster?

Comment: Can you share your use cases, why you are considering the hot warm arch?

Comment: basically data is more than the size of 10TB and it will grow eventually hence we are considering Hot warm architecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't be using individual IP to connect to a cluster as that can potentially become your single point of failure, if the node goes down. You should have a load balancing URL that connects to data nodes or coordinator nodes to aid your search.

Also, it looks like, you are having dedicated master nodes. Typically for larger size cluster, its not recommended to use master as the search coordinator and should ideally have them in master eligible only role to ensure cluster stability. So you will be left with option of using either data nodes or coordinator only nodes to accept your search requests.

If you are using clients like JEST, NEST etc and not directly using the http endpoint for _search, then you also have option to provide a list of IPs/hostname to form a connection pool.

Comment: Cool so a list of IPs/Hostname should be of the load balancers or the direct IP address of our elastic instance?. I am assuming here that we can have multiple load balancers when the number of node increases

Comment: if you are using load balancer, you will just use one URL and you GTM/LTM will handle the load balancing (mostly its round robin). If you dont have an explicit load balancer sitting in front, then only us the list of hostname/IPs of nodes to form your indiv connection pool for search req. Please remember that all searches are executed in 2 phases - scatter and gather. So the node that receives your search request, may or may not participate in actual search depending on where your underlying indices are present. If you expect to have high search volume, consider having coordinator only nodes.

Answer (score -1):

Like @askids mentioned, always connect to elasticsearch using the standard. Elastic itself provides clients. 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/index.html

You have not mentioned the clients you are going to be using. If your client is based on Java, use the Elasticsearch's Low-Level or High Level Rest Client. These clients are wrappers on apache http client and provide you all the boilerplate logic of handling connections and other features.
You can also add Sniffer support to it.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-low.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/sniffer.html

Comment: Yes you are obviously right I didn't explicitly state that into my question but I will be using  will be using PHP and GO API to connect to elastic client

Comment: Reg your comment in your accepted answer-Donot prefer to use just the loadbalancer by itself that sits infront of multiple nodes of the cluster. Though LB does a round-robin, you will miss important features such as of driver's internal Retry in case of errors and marking  the nodes dead when nodes go down. Use LB along with  Discover Nodes feature of the driver.  https://godoc.org/github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch#Client.DiscoverNodes and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/connection_pool.html#_sniffingconnectionpool (maynot need  for typical PHP usecases)

Comment: So just to clarify I need to add LB URL along with the list of other data node hosts while creating a connection pool in order to achieve the above feature?